# SharePoint 2013 API jQuery.Ajax Access Denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I am trying something simple - to retrieve list information from a SharePoint 2013 list. However, I am getting access denied when the jQuery Ajax is processed. I've tried setting up headers with the headers object and the beforeSend function, but with no success. Here is my jQuery.Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: { // also tried with Authentication
            "Authorization": someBasicCryptedCred,
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        url: "http://spSiteCollection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",
        type: "GET",
        success: SuccessProcess,
        error: ErrorProcess
    });
```

My application is a simple MVC Mobile app

I am following these documentation (along with some other from MSDN but cannot post more than 2 links):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870858.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163228.aspx

Comment: are you having this on a different domain? smells like a cross origin problem

Comment: is the sharepoint application on the same server? Maybe you running into [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy).

Comment: Yes, both my application and the SharePoint server are located on the same server.

Also, I've added the $.support.cors = true; on loading the page, otherwise I am getting NO TRANSPORT.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need the Form Digest Value, you can get with jQuery using:

```
$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val();
```

You can get it with API rest call, with /_api/ContextInfo and that retrieve a JSON object with other many fields apart of Form Digest Value.

```
http://<site url>/_api/contextinfo
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Form Digest value in the call, could that be the reason?

X-RequestDigest = form digest value

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142386%28office.15%29.aspx#bk_synchronize

This seems to be the approach, but as I try to send a "dummy" request to retrieve the form digest value I am getting again access denied - the URL is http://spSiteCollection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items/contextinfo, also tried with _api/web/lists/contextinfo and a few other combinations without success.

Comment: user2225566, thx for the direction. I have managed to fix the issue with making a dummy POST request to the contextinfo entry point of the REST service and then reading the X-RequestDigest value from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing, is looks like you are accessing cross site collection data from you app web, so please provide proper permission to your app through **"AppManifest.xml"** file. thats it and you are done.